# How to use Gulp to create a separate vendor bundle with Browserify from Bower components

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, gulp, browserify

I'm using [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) and [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to package my Javascript into 2 separate bundles: `application.js` and `vendor.js`.

How do I bundle the `vendor` package if my vendor libraries are installed with [Bower](http://bower.io/)?

In my gulpfile, I'm using the following modules:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var browserify = require("browserify");
var debowerify = require("debowerify");
var source = require("vinyl-source-stream");
```

Assuming that I have only the [Phaser framework](http://phaser.io/) installed with bower (for this example), my Gulp task to create the `application` package looks like this:

```
gulp.task("scripts-app", function () {
  browserify("./app/javascripts/index.js")
    .external("phaser")
    .pipe(source("application.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./tmp/assets"));
});
```

Meanwhile, the `vendor` task looks like this:

```
gulp.task("scripts-vendor", function () {
  browserify()
    .transform(debowerify)
    .require("phaser")
    .pipe(source("vendor.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./tmp/assets"));
});
```

When I run this Gulp task, I get an error that states `Error: Cannot find module 'phaser' from` and then all the directories it search through (none of which are the bower_components directory).

Any ideas about how to package these up successfully are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered my own question:

When using `require` in the Gulp task, you need to supply a path to a file, not just a name.

```
gulp.task("scripts-vendor", function () {
  browserify()
    .transform(debowerify)
    .require("./bower_components/phaser/phaser.js")
    .pipe(source("vendor.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./tmp/assets"));
});
```

Notice that `require("phaser")` became `require("./bower_components/phaser/phaser.js")`.

Doing this works, although the bundle takes forever to build (around 20 seconds). You're probably better of just loading giant libraries/frameworks directly into your app through a `<script>` tag and then using [Browserify Shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim).

This let's you `require()` (in the NodeJS/Browserify sense) global variables ([documentation](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim#a-expose-global-variables-via-global)).

Comment: You do not need debowerify when requiring by the full path. It seems like in this particular examples it works because debowerify actually does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you figured out how to require the bower file. Hopefully you'll only have to bundle it once initially, and not every build. Including the library via a script tag isn't a bad idea. Another technique I'm using is to use [scriptjs](http://www.dustindiaz.com/scriptjs) (a polyfill would work too), to async load whatever vender libraries I need, but make sure to include any/all require's after the script loads. For example, your index.js could be like:

```
$script.('/assets/vendor', function() {
  var phaser = require('phaser');
  //rest of code


});
```

It's especially nice for loading cdn files or having the ability to defer loading certain libraries that aren't necessarily used in the core app by every user, or loading libraries after client-side routing.

Comment: This does not answer how to create a browserified bundle from bower components.

Comment: I think I misread the question... he had all the correct modules, but he didn't include the path. I guess I thought he wanted another way to include the bower files that's similar to `<script></script>` async loading. I think it's good practice to separate large frameworks from the local dev bundle anyway, and this the pattern I'd use for including bower / 3rd party frameworks with browserify (with require enabled such that writing the code is identical, only the initialization is different because it's not prebundled)